# Is there any way of calling scala method (having type parameter ) with infix notation

Tags: scala, dsl, implicit, structural-typing

I have a piece of code in implicit class -

```
implicit class Path(bSONValue: BSONValue) {
      def |<[S, T <:{def value:S}] = {
        bSONValue.asInstanceOf[T].value
      }

}
```

The problem is if I want to call `|<` method after BSONValue I need to call with `.` .
e.g

```
(doc/"_id").|<[String,BSONString]
```

The problem is without `.` scala raises error because it does not allow type parameter method with infix notation. So always I have to wrap  `doc/"_id"` portion with `()`.
Is their any way of using type parameter method without `.` eg

```
doc/"_id"|<[String,BSONString]
```

Comment: I would recommend you to rethink your API. It is not only hard to read but I guess you wouldn't want to specify either `String` or `BSONString` but just one of them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez , nice suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All types `T` that you want to get out of `BSONValue`s will probably have a companion object with the same name. You could use that companion object as an intuitive placeholder for the type that you actually want to get. Something along these lines:

```
trait Extract[A, BComp, B] {
  def extractValue(a: A): B
}

implicit class Extractable[A](a: A) {
  def |<[BC, B]
    (companion: BC)
    (implicit e: Extract[A, BC, B])
  : B = e.extractValue(a)
}

implicit def extractIntFromString
  : Extract[String, Int.type, Int] = _.toInt

implicit def extractDoubleFromString
  : Extract[String, Double.type, Double] = _.toDouble

val answer = "42" |< Int
val bnswer = "42.1" |< Double
```

This allows you to use infix syntax, because all those things are ordinary values.

---

Still, only because it's possible, it doesn't mean that you have to do it.
For instance, I wouldn't know what to expect from a `|<`-operator.
Many other people also wouldn't know what to do with it.
They'd have to go and look it up. Then they would see this signature:

```
def |<[BC, B](companion: BC)(implicit e: Extract[A, BC, B]): B
```

I can imagine that the vast majority of people (myself in one week included) would not be immediately enlightened by this signature.

Maybe you could consider something more lightweight:

```
type BSONValue = String

trait Extract[B] {
  def extractValue(bsonValue: BSONValue): B
}


def extract[B](bson: BSONValue)(implicit efb: Extract[B])
  : B = efb.extractValue(bson)

implicit def extractIntFromString
  : Extract[Int] = _.toInt

implicit def extractDoubleFromString
  : Extract[Double] = _.toDouble

val answer = extract[Int]("42")
val bnswer = extract[Double]("42.1")

println(answer)
println(bnswer)
```

It seems to do roughly the same as the `|<` operator, but with much less magic going on.